# Deriving velocity of sound in a relativistic perfect fluid from weinberg

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics

The following derivation is from Weinberg's gravitation and cosmology.

$o=\frac{\partial N^\alpha}{\partial x^\alpha}=\frac{\partial ({nU^\alpha})}{\partial x^\alpha}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}({n(1-v^2)^{-1/2})}+\nabla\cdot({nv(1-v^2)^{-1/2}}) \tag{2.10.15}$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+(v\cdot\nabla)\ v=\frac{-(1-v^2)}{p+\rho}[\nabla p+\frac{v\partial p}{\partial t}] \tag{2.10.16}$

$kTd\sigma=pd{}(\frac{1}{n})+d(\frac{\rho}{n}) \tag{2.10.18}$

$0=U^\beta\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x^\beta} \propto \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t}+(v.\nabla)\sigma \tag{2.10.19}$

"In the unperturbed state we have n,$\rho$,p and $\sigma$ constant in space and time. According to 2.10.19 it leaves $\sigma$ unchanged. To first order in small quantities eqs.2.10.15 and 2.10.16 then read

$\partial_tn_1+ n\nabla\cdot v_1=0 $

$\partial_tv_1=\frac{-\nabla p_1}{p+\rho}$

with $d\sigma=0$ eq 2.10.18 gives

$0=\frac{-p+\rho}{n}n_1+\rho_1$

so that,

$\partial_tv_1=\frac{-v_s^2\nabla n_1}{n}$

where $v_s^2=\frac{p_1}{\rho_1}=(\frac{\partial p} {\partial \rho})_ {\sigma constant} \tag{2.10.31}$

combining equations of $n_1$ and $v_1$ we obtain a wave equation,

$0=[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-v^2\nabla^2]n_1$

that shows that sound wave travels with speed $v_s$

In this, how do we get to
$\partial_tv_1=\frac{-v_s^2\nabla n_1}{n}$ from the steps above?

Comment: Here velocity itself exist as first order perturbation $v=v_1<<1$. Similarly, only  perturbation of the pressure term will have gradient and time-derivative. Simply expand 2.10.16 upto 1st order in all perturbation.

Comment: @KP99 But that just gives $\partial_tv_1=\frac{-\nabla p_1}{p+\rho}$  right?.  How this becomes $\partial_tv_1=\frac{-v_s^2\nabla n_1}{n}$